# helm deployments with readynessprobe

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am using helm in my CI to upgrade deployments with newer versions of charts.

```
helm upgrade --wait --install .
```

**Expected behavior:**
the --wait flag should wait for the readinessProbe defined in the new chart.
See also:
https://docs.helm.sh/helm/#helm-upgrade

However, it does not wait and simply deploys the new chart, even if the readinessProbe is failing.

Which results in a failed new chart and a killed old chart.

It has nothing to do with 
https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3173, as the readinessProbe is properly executed and fails. But Helm does simply not wait for this.

Did anybody face issues like that? 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the relevant YAML file?  I haven't had great luck with `helm install --wait`, but in general Kubernetes Deployments won't start killing off old pods until the new ones are health-checking successfully.

Comment: Which version helm you use?

Comment: I used helm 2.9.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Issue was fixed by setting the following Kubernetes yaml description inside the deployment ressource:

```
  strategy:
   type: RollingUpdate
   rollingUpdate:
    maxSurge: 1
    maxUnavailable: 0
```

[Kubernetes Deployment Documentation:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)

> Note: The Deployment controller will stop the bad rollout
>   automatically, and will stop scaling up the new ReplicaSet. This
>   depends on the rollingUpdate parameters (maxUnavailable specifically)
>   that you have specified. Kubernetes by default sets the value to 1 and
>   .spec.replicas to 1 so if you haven’t cared about setting those
>   parameters, your Deployment can have 100% unavailability by default!
>   This will be fixed in Kubernetes in a future version.